# Get a value of array in range based index in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, laravel, controller

I want to get 1-3 value of array but include '.' every split.

Example there is a text `no.this.is.just.example`

I want to take just 0-2 index so $merge will be `no.this.is`

I tried

```
$cut = 3;
$text = explode('.',"no.this.is.just.example");

for($i=0; $i<$cut;$i++){
   if($cut-1==$i){
     $merge .= $text[$i];
   }
   else{
     $merge .= $text[$i].'.';
   }
}
```

Is there the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean pass 3 as the last parameter to explode? `$text = explode('.',"no.this.is.just.example", $cut);`

Comment: Or, just `preg_match('~^[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){3}~', $s, $match)` will do (`$match[0]` will contain the result). Or, the regex can even be `^(?:\.?[^.]*){4}` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w4oR7G/1)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could avoid the loop entirely by using a combination of [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$cut = 3;
$text = explode('.', 'no.this.is.just.example');

echo implode('.', array_slice($text, 0, $cut)); 

// outputs no.this.is
```

Comment: in the parameter array_slice $cut doesn't need -1? i mean echo implode('.', array_slice($text, 0, $cut-1));. because the index start on 0

Comment: No, from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), the 3rd parameter defines the length of the sequence..

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to pass `$cut` as the third parameter to explode <sup>[doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)</sup>. *The returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string* so add 1 to the limit.

Then use array_slice [<sup>doc</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the part you want.

```
$cut = 3;
$text = explode('.',"no.this.is.just.example", $cut + 1);
echo implode('.', array_slice($text, 0, $cut));
```

Result

```
no.this.is
```

Answer (score 0):

while loops are the simplest type of loop in PHP. They behave just like their C counterparts.

```
$cut = 3;
$text = explode('.',"no.this.is.just.example");
while($cut > 0) {
  $merge .= $text[$i].'.';
  $cut--;
}
```